# Ошибка при установке pyinstaller

Tags: python, cmd, pip

Вот такая ошибка при установке

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Запусти `cmd` под администратором и попробуй еще раз, либо установи пакет для пользователя: `pip install pyinstaller --user`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте откатить версию pip до 18.1:

python -m pip install pip==18.1

потом установить pyinstaller:

pip install pyinstaller

потом обновить pip до последней версии:

python -m pip install –U pip